# How to import Sass modules in Next.js components

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js

With the latest Next.js I can import Sass styles globally in `pages/_app.js` with a directive like `import '../styles/global.scss';` and without depending on `@zeit/next-sass`.

Does this work at the component level? For example, can I have a `components/*` directory where I keep my components, and each component has a `*.tsx` file that imports a `*.module.scss` file?

That's not working for me right now. I don't get errors but component-level styles don't load while the global styles do.

Edit: To be clear, I do *not* want to import an object like `import styles from ...scss`. I simply want to import Sass for this component, not any object that has properties.

Here's a code example where I can see the `globals.scss` styles but not the `Main.module.scss` styles when I run it with `npx run dev`.

From scratch I ran `npx create-next-app _` and then `npm install sass`. There are only five important files, once I make a simple `Main` component that I want to style:

- `components/Main/Main.tsx` :

```
import './Main.module.scss';

export default function Main() {
  return <div className="Main">Main</div>;
};
```

- `components/Main/Main.module.scss` :

This rule is not applied for some reason!

```
.Main {
    color: blue;
}
```

- `pages/_app.js` :

These global styles do get applied!

```
import '../styles/globals.scss';

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
};
```

- `pages/index.js` :

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Main from '../components/Main/Main';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <Main />

    </div>
  )
};
```

- `styles/globals.scss` :

This style rule is applied but not `color: blue` above.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Yes, Sass (including Sass modules) has built-in support in Next.js as long as you install `sass` with `npm install sass`. Could you provide a code example where you're trying to use Sass modules?

Comment: but protip: don't bundle your CSS into your JS. Make your sass a separate build step and keep it a plain-ass static resource so browsers can cache it independently and your index.html can load it with a standard `<link>`. js-css and js-sass might seem convenient, but they _don't need webpack or bundling or anything like it_ to work. Just run your sass compile independent of your JS bundle. Your users deserve it.

Comment: @juliomalves I added a code example
@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Totally agree with you, all I want to do is structure my project so each component is in `components/*/*.tsx` and has styles in `components/*/*.module.scss`.

Comment: @Ganymede To clarify your last edit, you have to import Sass modules as an object and use its properties. You can't import it like global Sass, because it's scoped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because Sass modules scope the class names within the modules they are used, you'll need to import it as an object (`styles` in this example) and each class is accessed as a property on the imported object.

```js
import styles from './Main.module.scss';

export default function Main() {
    return <div className={styles.Main}>Main</div>;
};
```

Comment: This was the answer (using `styles.Main`) and I think it should be better documented. Also: vscode seems to mistakenly report the `import styles from ...` line as an error, even though the code builds and runs (red squiggly line saying 'cannot find module').

Comment: There's a reference to it in the [CSS Modules section](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css) of the documentation, which directly translates to Sass as well. However, I agree - could use better documentation.

Comment: Is there a reason Next.js (or sass) adds a class name like `Main_Main__y3p83` to my `Main` component? I mean, in the generated html I see `<div class="Main Main_Main__y3p83">Main</div>`. I didn't add the second class.

Comment: Sass Modules locally scope Sass by automatically creating a unique class name. This allows you to use the same class name in different files without worrying about collisions. It's just how Sass Modules work.